# I have a problem with foreign key constraintt

Tags: oracle11g

```
ALTER TABLE class_s19_BM ADD CONSTRAINT fk_std_class FOREIGN KEY(std_id) REFERENCES student_s19_BM (std_id); /
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00904: "STD_ID": invalid identifier

Comment: show student_s19_BM table, is it in same scheme as class_s19_BM ?

Comment: Either the table `class_s19_bm` or the table `student_s19_bm` does not have a column named `std_id`